# $orderby not working with lookup column Id

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, rest

I want to sort order my REST results data with a lookup column's Id in my SharePoint list.

I tried using $orderby in my REST query, but got no luck.

can anyone of you help me out with this ?

below is the query I am using and in that "CourseTitle" is the field based on whose Id I want to order the result. Please note that I want to sort by Id only, Not by LookUp Title.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Training Evaluation')/items/?$select=Title,Id,CourseTitle/Id,CourseTitle/Title&$expand=CourseTitle&$orderby=CourseTitle"
```

Comment: I could replicate your issue. `OrderBy` always sorts lookup title, not id. You can try sorting it after you get all the items using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Training Evaluation')/items/?$select=Title,Id,CourseTitle/Id,CourseTitle/Title&$expand=**CourseTitle/Id**&$orderby=**CourseTitle/Id**"`

Comment: not working, it seems that orderby itself doesn't have any significance in my rest query